# Backbone - Anyway to check if an event has been bound before?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm doing this inside one of my Views:

```
render: function($options) {
    ...

    this.collection.on('reset', _(function() {
        this.render($options);
    }).bind(this));

    ....
}
```

The problem is, whenever `reset` as well as the re-rendering has been triggered, a new `reset` binding will be created, resulting 2x, 4x, 8x, etc. times of re-rendering as it goes on.

It's a bit tricky to move the binding into the initialize section (which should solve this issue), however since it's not an option, is there any other solution available, like having Backbone checking if this event has been bound before, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving your binding to `initialize` would be best but assuming that you have good reasons not to, you could just set a flag:

```
initialize: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this._finish_initializing = _.once(function($options) {
        _this.collection.on('reset', function() {
            _this.render($options);
        });
    });
    //...
},
render: function($options) {
    this._finish_initializing($options);
    //...
}
```

There are lots of different ways to implement the flag, [`_.once`](http://underscorejs.org/#once) just nicely hides the flag checking. You could also trigger an event in `render` have a listener that unbinds itself:

```
initialize: function() {
    var finish_initializing = function($options) {
        /* your binding goes here ... */
        this.off('render', finish_initializing);
    };
    this.on('render', finish_initializing, this);
},
render: function($options) {
    this.trigger('render', $options);
    //...
}
```

That's the same logic really, just dressed up in different clothes. You could also use an explicit flag and an `if` in `render` or assign a function to `this._finish` in `initialize` and that function would `delete this._finish`.

Answer (score 1):

> like having Backbone checking if this event has been bound before, or something?

Sure..

```
!!this.collection._events["render"]
```

Backbone doesn't expose most of the API required to make it useful. That's alright, use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, define your event handler function as a named function

```
var self = this;
var onReset = function() {
    self.render($options);
}
```

Then, defensively unbind the function each time render is called

```
this.collection.off('reset', onReset);
this.collection.on('reset', onReset);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently accomplished this using a javascript variable.

Outside of any functions, I declared:

```
var boundalready =0
```

Then, inside the function:

```
if (boundalready == 0){
      boundalready = 1;
      bind(this);
    };
```

This worked for me pretty well.