# Prevent Backbone event from triggering more than once, how to check if event is registered already?

Tags: backbone.js

In my router object, I created an event object to share among my views

I pass the event object to my views

I register events to this shared object like this

```
var productCatalogView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function (options) {
                     //bind alert event to sharedEvents
                    options.sharedEvents.bind("alert", this.alert,this);
                },
      alert: function () {
                    alert('alerted');
                }
    });
```

//The following view triggers the alert event

```
 var testView = Backbone.View.extend({

            initialize: function (options) {
                this.sharedEvents = options.sharedEvents;
            },
            events: {
                 'click #test': 'triggerAlert'
            },

            triggerAlert: function (e) {
                this.sharedEvents.trigger("alert", null);

            }           

        });
```

THE PROBLEM:
The problem I experience is that the first time I click on the button which triggers the alert event (second view), the alert event gets called once (good), this causes the first view to be re-rendered by triggering the route passing search parameters, therefore creating the first view and binding the sharedEvents again, hence when I trigger the alert event a second time, it gets triggered twice (bad), the next time I repeat the same process, it gets triggered 3 times, and so on and so forth. I guess it has to do with the event binding in the first view, it occurs more than once, i.e each time the view is initialized (if I am correct) 
please how can I make the binding of the event occur once.

Here is my router which shows how I initilze the views:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    sharedEvents:_.extend({},Backbone.Events),

    catalog: function (id) {

       //....unecessary code left out

        var productView = new ProductView({sharedEvents:this.sharedEvents});

            this.renderView(productView);
            this.renderView(new testView({sharedEvents: this.sharedEvents }));
       }

      renderView: function (view) {
                if (null != this.currentView) {
                    this.currentView.undelegateEvents();
                    // this.currentView.remove();
                }
                this.currentView = view;
                this.currentView.render();
            }

});
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399181/backbone-anyway-to-check-if-an-event-has-been-bound-before)  solution but problem persists, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try using Backbone.Events' `listenTo` method instead of the `bind` method. Then, in your `renderView()`, call `this.currentView.remove` instead of `this.currentView.undelegateEvents`.

Rationale:

I believe in your `renderView()` method, you are using `undelegateEvents()` thinking it releases all event listeners created by your view. It *only* releases events bound on to your view's `$el` element. However, using `remove()` on the view releases events bound to the `$el` as well as events created using `this.listenTo()` (and `this.listenOnce()`).

Now once you render another view, the old `currentView` will be properly released and you'll only get one alert.

Comment: Thanks, it seems when I use .remove() instead of .undelegateEvents(), the view and the el are removed, this causes nothing to be rendered on th UI when I render the next view, this I guess is because .remove() actually removes the the div that el points to which I append all view templates to, any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Ah, if you're having multiple views share the same dom element, use `this.currentView.undelegateEvents()` and `this.currentView.stopListening()` to achieve roughly the same thing.

Comment: I changed the code to use listenTo instead of on, but it seems the event isn't being triggered now from the second view, this is the only changed i tried now      options.sharedEvents.listenTo(this,"alert",this.alert);

Comment: I should have made this more clear in my answer. `listenTo` inverts the management of the event handler. Instead of `options.sharedEvents.bind("alert", this.alert, this);`, you would use `this.listenTo(options.sharedEvents, 'alert', this.alert)`.

Comment: Its works fine now, I called the two methods serially this way               options.sharedEvents.stopListening(options.sharedEvents, "alert", this.alert);
                options.sharedEvents.listenTo(options.sharedEvents, "alert", this.alert); i.e, i stop listening before I begin listening